# A Lady Drinking Tea

Tags: combinatorics

A lady named Jane comes along and claims that she can tell the difference between tea that is sweetened and tea that is unsweetened. We decide to test her by preparing N = 10 cups of tea, half of which are sweetened and half of which are unsweetened. We also decide to prepare an answer key.

Let me repeat for emphasis: we are testing her ability to taste the difference. This is important.

Cup #1:  Unsweetened (henceforth "U")

Cup #2:  Sweetened (henceforth "S")

Cup #3:  S

Cup #4:  S

Cup #5:  U

Cup #6:  S

Cup #7:  U

Cup #8:  S

Cup #9:  U

Cup #10: U

Suppose that, like most people, Jane has perfect tea-tasting ability and can perfectly tell the difference between sweet or bitter. One response she could give is this:

Cup #1:  U  U

Cup #2:  S  S

Cup #3:  S  S

Cup #4:  S  S

Cup #5:  U  U

Cup #6:  S  S

Cup #7:  U  U

Cup #8:  S  S

Cup #9:  U  U

Cup #10: U  U

But another response she could give, which just as powerfully proves her perfect tea-tasting ability and thus is equivalent to the first one, is this

Cup #1:  U  S

Cup #2:  S  U

Cup #3:  S  U

Cup #4:  S  U

Cup #5:  U  S

Cup #6:  S  U

Cup #7:  U  S

Cup #8:  S  U

Cup #9:  U  S

Cup #10: U  S

Or to put it in pictorial form

[image: Diagram]

Both of these responses partition the set of distinguishable teacups into two disjoint sets, which is what we're measuring. How do we count the number of ways to do this?

EDIT: The above is merely an example. The question I am really asking, in formal, combinatorial terms, is this: Suppose we have N combinatorial objects, k of which are of one flavor and N - k of which are some other flavor. How many distinguishable ways are there to partition N into two disjoint subsets?

Comment: I am a little confused by your question. When you say "How many distinguishable ways are there to partition N into two disjoint subsets?" Is there a necessary constraint that each of the subsets must only contain items of the same flavor?

Comment: Good question. No it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the comment, if the $k$ cups of one flavor are indistinguishable, you just have to choose a number from $0$ to $k$ of that flavor to be in the first subset.  Then you choose a number from $0$ to $N-k$ of the other flavor to be in the first subset, giving $(k+1)(N-k+1)$ ordered choices.  We divide by $2$ to get unordered choices unless both $k$ and $N-k$ are even and we put exactly half of each in each subset.  So we have $\frac 12(k+1)(N-k+1) [+\frac 12]$ where the last square bracket is added in only if both $k$ and $N$ are even.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of my example. The question, in formal, combinatorial terms, is this:

Suppose we have N combinatorial objects, k of which are of one flavor and N - k of which are some other flavor. How many distinguishable ways are there to partition N into two disjoint subsets?